# How to cache utils function used in different class instances using lru_cache?

Tags: python, caching

When using `lru_cache` in a utilities module, after decorating a method, and calling from two different class instances, I found that the `cache_info()` showed only one hit each time the decorated method was called.

*awsUtils.py*:

```
@lru_cache(maxsize=32)
def getRdsDetailsCached(name, region):
  return getRdsDetails(name, region):

def getRdsDetails(name, region):
  client = boto3.client('rds', region)
  response = client.describe_db_instances(DBInstanceIdentifier=name,)
  return response['DBInstances']
```

*Replication.py*

```
class Replication(ActionBase):

  def __init__(self, **entries):
    super().__init__(**entries)
    self.rdsDetails = awsUtils.getRdsDetailsCache('my-db', 'us-west-2')
```

*Postgress.py*

```
class Postgress(DependencyBase):

  def __init__(self, **entries):
    super().__init__(**entries)
    self.rdsDetails = awsUtils.getRdsDetailsCache('my-db', 'us-west-2')
```

When the above two classes are initialized, I would expect the first instance to call `awsUtils.getRdsDetailsCache` which would create a cache, and any other instance would re-use that cache.  However the actual result is each shows that the hit count is 1.

[image: Image showing cache result after second call to getRdsDetailsCache]

Comment: That's showing it working correctly; the first call was a miss, the second a hit. Two calls total, one result stored in the cache. Also note you don't need the extra "...Cached" function, just apply the decorator to the regular version.

Comment: OK, I added a third call from another class.  These classes are using a composite pattern, as there maybe other classes that might need uncached data, I chose to add a separate function.  But here is what I got...

`awsUtils.getRdsDetailsCache.cache_info()`

`CacheInfo(hits=0, misses=1, maxsize=32, currsize=1)`

`awsUtils.getRdsDetailsCache.cache_info()`

`CacheInfo(hits=0, misses=2, maxsize=32, currsize=2)`

`awsUtils.getRdsDetailsCache.cache_info()`

`CacheInfo(hits=1, misses=2, maxsize=32, currsize=2)`

... maybe I am not understanding what a "miss" or "hit" is?

Comment: And what about that makes you think it's not working? A miss is a request whose result isn't found in the cache, as opposed to a hit whose result *is*.

Comment: I understand now... thanks for the clarity of hit/miss.  In the case above I see currsize was 2, which led me to the realization I was passing in a different argument value for one of the calls.  Thanks for the help!